# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding, praw

I'm new to Python and I've been trying to fix it for two hours now.

Here's the code:

```
import praw
import json
import requests
import tweepy
import time

access_token = 'REDACTED'
access_token_secret = 'REDACTED'
consumer_key = 'REDACTED'
consumer_secret = 'REDACTED'

def strip_title(title):
    if len(title) < 94:
        return title
    else:
        return title[:93] + "..."

def tweet_creator(subreddit_info):
    post_dict = {}
    post_ids = []
    print "[bot] Getting posts from Reddit"
    for submission in subreddit_info.get_hot(limit=20):
        post_dict[strip_title(submission.title)] = submission.url
        post_ids.append(submission.id)
    print "[bot] Generating short link using goo.gl"
    mini_post_dict = {}
    for post in post_dict:
        post_title = post
        post_link = post_dict[post]         
        short_link = shorten(post_link)
        mini_post_dict[post_title] = short_link 
    return mini_post_dict, post_ids

def setup_connection_reddit(subreddit):
    print "[bot] setting up connection with Reddit"
    r = praw.Reddit('yasoob_python reddit twitter bot '
                'monitoring %s' %(subreddit)) 
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(subreddit)
    return subreddit

def shorten(url):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {"longUrl": url}
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    link = json.loads(r.text)['id']
    return link

def duplicate_check(id):
    found = 0
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if id in line:
                found = 1
    return found

def add_id_to_file(id):
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(id) + "\n")

def main():
    subreddit = setup_connection_reddit(‘python’)
    post_dict, post_ids = tweet_creator(subreddit)
    tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)

def tweeter(post_dict, post_ids):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    for post, post_id in zip(post_dict, post_ids):
        found = duplicate_check(post_id)
        if found == 0:
            print "[bot] Posting this link on twitter"
            print post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #python"
            api.update_status(post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #python")
            add_id_to_file(post_id)
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print "[bot] Already posted" 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Traceback:

```
root@li732-134:~# python twitter.py
[bot] setting up connection with Reddit
[bot] Getting posts from Reddit
[bot] Generating short link using goo.gl
[bot] Already posted
[bot] Already posted
[bot] Already posted
[bot] Posting this link on twitter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter.py", line 82, in <module>
main()
File "twitter.py", line 64, in main
tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)
File "twitter.py", line 74, in tweeter
print post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #python"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 39:       
ordinal not in range(128)`
```

I really have no idea what to do. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Added code and traceback.

Comment: Post the code *here*, then give us the full error traceback.

Comment: Done, it's there now.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you call `decode()`, the bytes you're receiving have to be in an expected, properly encoded form.

If `\xea` is encountered in a UTF-8 string, it *must* be followed by two bytes, and not just any bytes, they have to be in the valid range. Otherwise, it's not valid UTF-8.

E.g. here are two Unicode code points. The first code point `U+56` takes only a single byte. The next one, `U+a000` requires three bytes, and the way we know that is because we encounter `\xea`:

http://hexutf8.com/?q=0x560xea0x800x80

Simply remove the last of the continuation bytes in the above, and this ceases to be valid UTF-8:

http://hexutf8.com/?q=0x560xea0x80

I don't see where you've posted the value you're failing on, but I'd double-check that and make sure you're actually getting valid UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens here:

```
print post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #python"
```

The problem seems to be that you're concatenating ASCII strings and Unicode strings in this line. That's causing a problem here. Try concatenating only Unicode strings:

```
print post + u" " + post_dict[post] + u" #python"
```

If you're still having problems, look at the output of `type(post)` and `type(post_dict[post])` which should both be Unicode strings. If either of them isn't then you'll need to convert them to be a Unicode string using the correct encoding (most likely UTF-8). That can be done as follows:

```
post.decode('UTF-8')
```

or:

```
post_dict[post].decode('UTF-8')
```

The above would convert a string to a Unicode string in Python 2. Once you've done that you can safely concatenate the Unicode strings together. The key thing in Python 2 is to never mix regular strings with Unicode strings as that'll cause problems.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. I've added `print post + u" " + post_dict[post].decode('UTF-8') + u" #test"` but I am getting the same error. I've also tried `print post+" "+post_dict[post].decode('UTF-8')+" #test"`

Comment: @KevinSmith: you'll most likely need to decode both, so `post` as well. Otherwise you're still concatenating an ASCII string with other Unicode strings.

Comment: @SimonVisser: `print post.decode('UTF-8')+" "+post_dict[post].decode('UTF-8')+" #test"` produces the error `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode` `return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)` `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @KevinSmith: you've left out the `u` in front of the strings in between so those are now still ASCII strings. All variables need to have a `.decode` call and all other strings need to have `u` in front. If you're still getting errors after you've done that, then the variables may not contain UTF-8 (but your error message should no longer mention ASCII at that point).

Comment: `print post.decode('UTF-8') + u" " + post_dict[post].decode('UTF-8') + u" #python"` produces the exact same error as before.

Comment: @KevinSmith: is your terminal encoding set to ASCII perhaps? If you assign the whole string to a variable and then try to print that variable on the next line, does Python succeed in creating that variable (i.e., does the error happen on the line where you print and not on the line where you assign to the variable)?

Comment: The character it's having problems with is ê, if that changes anything.